# Problems with Visual Studio 2013 debugger - The debugging target and the debugger engine failed to initialize because of unspecified device errors

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, netduino

I am a hobbyist-programmer and build a few nice working solutions on NetDuino Plus 2 in C#. Recently I acquired the new Netduino 3 Ethernet. My problem is that the debugger does not work. When I load my C# application I get an error message:

> The debugging target and the debugger engine failed to initialize because of unspecified device errors.
>   The debugger engine thread has terminated unexpectedly with error 'Could not reconnect to the debugging target after rebooting it.'.

I have been looking on the web for a solution for a number of days now and I found a few people with the same problem but without solutions. Some people had the problem only on specific PC's. It worked fine on one PC, the other threw the error above. Other people had the problem in VS2012 but not in VS2013. One solution pointed at modifying the debugger SW but that goes beyond my knowledge. It seems there is some sensitivity in the debugger which has not been grasped yet..... Everything works fine with Netduino Plus 2, debugger always attaches. I have posted the problem also on the Netduino forum but without result.

Can someone point me in the right direction for a solution ?

Thanks in advance,

Arno

Comment: Maybe this helps http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/forum/31-netduino-3/

Comment: Oh, http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/12520-new-netduino-3-cyclic-reboot-please-help/